# PHP cast to integer with only 1 or 2 chars

Tags: php, casting

How can I cast to integer in PHP using only 1 or two chars?

If I have the operation `$a = (int) $b;` it will result using those two (or one) chars:

```
$a = <*insert the needed 1 or 2 chars*> $b;
```

I need only to cast to integer. Thank you.

Comment: Why does it need to be only 1 or 2 chars?

Comment: @alex: If I had to guess, I think it's because it could make code shorter for golfing.

Comment: @cavy were you doing a wechall challenge by any chance ?

Answer (score 3):

Prefix a `+` (the unary plus):

```
$a=+$b
```

A pretty common trick for code-golfing that also works in PowerShell and other languages.

```
$ php -r "var_dump('4');"
string(1) "4"
$ php -r "var_dump(+'4');"
int(4)
```

Comment: I knew there would be something like this... +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = sprintf("%02d", $b);
```

If you need to pad it with something other than zero, replace the zero with the character you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function, I guess. Of other type of shorter cast I'm unaware.

```
function z($i)
{
return (int)$i;
}

$a = z($b);
```